# Connecting to MySQL with XAMPP client in C

Tags: mysql, c, database, xampp

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  MYSQL *conn;
  MYSQL_RES *res;
  MYSQL_ROW row;

  char *server = "localhost";
  char *user = "root";
  char *password = ""; // set me first
  char *database = "VirtualSoc";
  conn = mysql_init(NULL);

  /* Connect to database */
  if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* send SQL query */
  if (mysql_query(conn, "show tables")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit(1);
  }
  res = mysql_use_result(conn);

  /* output table name */
  printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
  while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
    printf("%s \n", row[0]);

  /* close connection */
  mysql_free_result(res);
  mysql_close(conn);
}
```

This is the entire code. I'm trying to connect to a database under Linux.

How do I compile this?
Why am I getting an error saying that `mysql.h doesn't exist`?
Do I need to use something like libmysqlclient-dev or libmariadbclient-dev use `mysql.h`?

I don't want to use these, I just want to connect to my XAMPP server as localhost on my machine. How can I do that? And another question: why should I compile my code like this?

> $gcc -o output-file $(mysql_config --cflags) mysql-c-api.c $(mysql_config --libs)

Comment: To start with, try to format the code so it's actually readable. Indentation and spacing doesn't matter for the compiler, but it *do* matter for human beings.

Comment: To clarify some things: You don't have a separate XAMPP service, XAMPP is a *distribution* of multiple services, among them a database (MySQL) service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**,i found the answer and for those who want to use c to speak with the server(mysql) of **xampp** you need to **include** `#include "/opt/lampp/include/mysql.h"` (this is the **header**) and you have in the /include folder all of the **functions**,**macros** defined to connect and execute query's all day long. Thanks for the answers but you didn't uderstand me and you give me **very very wrong answers** for what i was looking for.I hope i will help in advance other people who want to do the same thing.

And i learned that no matter what service of what client you want to comunicate all the vast majority is owned and implemented with orcle technology and you need to install a `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` and you compile with

```
gcc -o example example.c `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is not able to find `mysql.h` in the system-defined `include` path. To correct this, you have to use `-I<path_to_header>` along with `gcc`.

IMO, it is recommeded to use the `" "` instead of `<>` with `#include` statement in your case.

Comment: To add to the answer: Adding the correct include/library paths is one thing that the `mysql_config` command should do in the OPs command line.

Comment: why I get `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` do I need to create directories or run as sudo su or users is enough?

Comment: it works ok with my normal mysql, but when I shift to xampp mysql it shows that error..so it seems that this /var/run/mysqld disappears when i stop the normal service and then i don't know how to fix this for xampp..any ideas?